# Get Child after Clicking on Parent in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a div that has two children. I want to check click event on parent node and add class to the specific child. my code is here:

```
<div class="popup">
  <span>Click</span>
  <span class="popuptext myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>

<script>
  $('.popup').click(function (e) {
  var popup = $(this).closest('span.myPopup')
  popup.addClass("show");
})
</script>
```

I have no error but the show class doesn't add to the span.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem with this code:

```
$('.popup').click(function (e) {
   $(this).find('span.myPopup').addClass('show')
   popup.addClass("show");
})
```